# Airflow All DAGs are queued after restarting the scheduler

Tags: airflow, celery

I have deployed an Airflow cluster for ETL pipeline with below components:

- Airflow 2.5
- PostgresSQL
- Celery Executor
- Redis

The cluster is functioning well, but I've noticed that every time I restart the Airflow scheduler, all my DAGs are queued forever until I manually restart the Airflow service in the worker node.

What is the reason behind?
Is there any configuration to move all queued DAGs to running state automatically?

Update on 2023-09-04
I am able to see this error message from the celery log, after restart the scheduler:

```bash
[2023-09-04 22:44:32,063: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:***:6379/5: Connection closed by server..
Trying again in 20.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

Unfortunately, I believe I am encountering the exact same issue as discussed in this thread.
https://github.com/celery/celery/discussions/7276

Comment: have you enabled [pgbouncer](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/1.1.0/production-guide.html#pgbouncer)? Not sure if that'll help, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

in your DAG, what is your start_Date and catchup value?

```
dag = DAG(
'my_dag',
start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
catchup=True,
# other parameters...
```

)

Do read more on [Airflow catchup](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#)

Comment: I have 100+ DAGs running with various start_date settings. Also I keep catchup_by_default = False in the airflow.cfg, so I suppose most of the DAG will be catchup=False.